# Accessing Pages that need authentication via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm trying to access a page that requires user authentication before that page is displayed.

How do I access this page? (I have the required user name and Password) I'm know we can use the XML HTTPrequest object to access other URLs via the script. But I'm not aware of any option that lets me authenticate first.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make a request to the authentication page, sending username and password. That would set a session cookie that the browser will handle on his own, then the session cookie will automatically be forwarded to the following requests you make, until the session expiral.

Remember however about the limits of cross-domain scripting, e.g. if the page you want to authenticate is in a different domain than the one the page the script is running in is the browser will likely refuse to make any request.

Actually this automatic cookie handling from the browser is the reason cross-domain scripting is insecure and thus forbidden for most sites.

Comment: I'm trying to this for a chromium extension I'm working on so there isn't a real clear page as such.
Can you explain the cross-domain access part in greater detail or give me some documentation thereof?

Comment: a rough description, with some references, can be found on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Basically you can't use XMLHttpRequest() on an URL whose protocol, domain or server port is different from the one of the page you're on.

I don't know how it works for extensions. Web servers can be configured to accept requests from different origin than the default ones.

Comment: After resolving the Same Origin Issue, this answer seems to work well.
Also +1 for explaining how it works.